# insertRowsAtIndexPaths: of custom UITableViewCells ends in unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: ios, uitableview, insert

I want to insert some custom cells in my `UITableView`.

So what I'm doing is simply this:

```
NSMutableArray *arrayOfCells = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for(int i = 0 ; i < 4 ; i++)
{
    CustomCell *cell = [[CustomCell alloc] init:myText];
    [arrayOfCells addObject:cell];
}
[table insertRowsAtIndexPaths:arrayOfCells withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationTop];
```

But the inserting line returns this error:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[CustomCell compare:]:
>   unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1cdebfb0'

Any idea why? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Is `CustomCell` a subclass of `UITableViewCell`?

Comment: Yes it is, `@interface CustomCell : UITableViewCell`

Comment: Mh at what line exactly does it crash. The error message is a hint that you either have not implemented compare in CustomCell and calling it or you have a memory management problem. Are you using ARC?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
NSMutableArray *arrayOfIndexPaths = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

for(int i = 0 ; i < 4 ; i++)
{
    NSIndexPath *path = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:0];
    [arrayOfIndexPaths addObject:path];
}

[table insertRowsAtIndexPaths:arrayOfIndexPaths withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationTop];
```

This is what you need to do.

Answer (score 2):

`insertRowsAtIndexPaths` takes as its parameter an array of `NSIndexPath` objects which represent where in the table the new rows should be. The table view then calls the delegate and dataSource to get the new cells and content to display.

You can not directly pass the new cells you want to be added...

Answer (score 0):

In short, you need to add the new cell to your array of cells, and insert them inside updates.
create an array of indexPaths like this:

```
NSMutableArray *indexPaths = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
for (int i = firstIndexPathValue; i < lastIndexPathValue; i++) [indexPaths addObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:0]];
```

then..

```
[myTableView beginUpdates];
//here is where you need to add objects to your array, then..
[myTableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:index withRowAnimation:chooseARowAnimation];
[myTableView endUpdates];
```